# How to scroll the div in my case?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to scroll my div content base on what links the user clicks.

http://jsfiddle.net/BPB7z/11/

My codes works fine when I am without scrolling down. However, If I scroll down and click link, the content will be scrolled to top instead of current top position.

For example.

```
        //works fine without scrolling the windows.
 ------------------------------------ <- top of my browser
    test1    | test1
    test2    |
    test3    |
             |
             |
             |
             | test2
```

If I scroll down my windows and clicks test 9 link. The test 9 div will be hidden like

```
-------------------------------   <- top of my browser.
test9     | 
test10    |
test11    |test10
test12    |
          |
          |
          |
```

Can someone help me out on this issue? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You've set the height to 900px.  That's taller than the height of the browser, so you now have 2 scrollbars.  If you've scrolled down the browser scroll (rather than just the `#items` scroll) then the top of that div is hidden off the page at the top.

Comment: Exactly - that's the situation he's asked how to address, and the purpose for the question here.

Comment: Ok. I interpreted it as something that happened when you scrolled down the overflowed auto div.  I added the comment in case the OP wasn't aware that the browser itself was also being scrolled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I understand your question correctly. If so, this small update will work:

http://jsfiddle.net/BPB7z/13/

```
$('#items').animate({
   scrollTop: $('#'+id+'-test').offset().top - $(window).scrollTop() + $('#items').scrollTop()
}, 700);
```

By subtracting `$(window).scrollTop()` value, we find the true position to animate to, taking into account the window's current scroll position.